# Jenkins console logs get truncated upon writing to a file

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to get full Jenkins consoleText and write it to a file as following:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

currentBuild.rawBuild.getLogText().writeLogTo(0, stream)
writeFile file: "archive/${jobName}-log.txt", text: stream.toString()
```

However, the contents of the file are getting truncated intermittently.

Jenkins version: 2.361.1

The size of the stream is 32 bytes initially and it is increased if needed.
I noticed that the size of the truncated files is 1.2-1.5 MB but the size of the original file is around 3 MB.
Could there be some memory issues?

Also, there is no problem with the files that are < 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get a copy of the console log you can do something like the below in your Pipeline.

```
sh"""
cp ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log archive/${JOB_NAME}-log.txt
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I run this command I get an error "No such file or directory" because I'm copying from URL which is not a file or directory

Comment: I'm using consoleText instead of log , I don't think that 'log' is a valid endpoint in my case

Answer (score 0):

sh"""
curl ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/consoleText -o archive/${JOB_NAME}-log.txt
"""